# why cascading is not working in country and state

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToSdy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfvxb.png)

why this happen they are view model controller respectively.

My code is not running but it fetch the data from the database.
How I can resolve this problem please help me.

and thanks in advance.

```js
function getcountry()
    {
       $this->db->select('*');
       $query = $this->db->get('et_country');
       return $query->result();
    }

    function getstate($country_id='')
    {
       $array = array('status' => 'Active','country_id' => $country_id);
       $this->db->select('id,name,country_id');
       $this->db->where($array);
       $query = $this->db->get('et_state');
       return $query->result();
    }
    
    function getcity($state_id='')
    {
       $array = array('status' => 'Active','state_id' =>  $state_id);
       $this->db->select('id,name,state_id');
       $this->db->where($array);
       $query = $this->db->get('et_city');
       return $query->result();
    }
```

```css
 public function create_subadmin()
    {
        $this->load->model('Auction_model');
        $data['country'] = $this->Auction_model->getcountry();           
        $this->load->view('admin/Auction/add_Auction',$data);   
    }
  
    public function ajax_state_list($country_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Auction_model');
        $data['state'] = $this->Auction_model->getstate($country_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/Auction/add_Auction',$data);
    }
    
    public function ajax_city_list($state_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Auction_model');
        $data['city'] = $this->Auction_model->getcity($state_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/Auction/add_Auction',$data);
    }
```

```html
<script>
            function getstatedetails(id)
            {
                //alert('this id value :'+id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/Auction_controller/ajax_state_list').'/';?>'+id,
                    data: id='cat_id',
                    success: function(data){
                //        alert(data);
                        $('#old_state').html(data);
                    },
                });
            }
            </script>
            <script>
            function getcitydetails(id)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/Auction_controller/ajax_city_list').'/';?>'+id,
                    data: id='st_id',
                    success: function(data){
                       
                        $('#old_city').html(data);
                    },
                });
            }
                </script>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Country</label><br>
                                <select name="country_id" class="form-control" id="country_details" onChange="getstatedetails(this.value)">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $rs->name ?>" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($country_id as $rs) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $rs->id; ?>"><?php echo $rs->name ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>State</label><br>
                                <select name="state_id" class="form-control" id="old_state" onChange="getstatedetails(this.value)">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $rs->name ?>" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    
                                    foreach ($state_id as $rs) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $rs->id; ?>"><?php echo $rs->name ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label><br>
                                <select name="city_id" class="form-control" id="old_city" onChange="getcitydetails(this.value)">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($city_id as $rs) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $rs->id; ?>"><?php echo $rs->name ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ajax call like this :

var values = {
              'cat_id': id
          };

```
$.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/Auction_controller/ajax_state_list').'/';?>"+id,
              type: "post",
              data: values,
              success: function(data) {
                   $('#old_state').html(data);
              }
          });
```

Comment: it still not working can you please give me some other ans

Comment: It won't so any error what happening is when I select country it will fetch the country but it make state option blank. even after selecting any country

Comment: my controller url is controller/admin/auction_controller

Comment: my model url is model/admin/Auction_model

Comment: my view url is view/admin/Auction/add_Auction

Comment: is there any problem in url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/Auction_controller/ajax_state_list').'/';?>"+id,

Comment: please check the country_id in  ajax_state_list and confirm that its correct.  either you can access country_id using $this->uri->segment() or by loading url library